# The State of OffScreen pages of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager which has multiple fragments. Each fragment has a Chrnometer which displays time on the Page/Fragment Activity.

1. Each fragment overrides onPause and onResume methods to stop and start the Chronometer.
2. I have realized that the Chronometer on the OffScreen pages do not stop.
3. This happens with only offscreen fragments.
4. Is the state of the activity of the OffScreen pages is not changing?

Competently lost on this issue. Appreciate any help on this issue.  Below is the code snippet

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    timeWhenStopped = chronometer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    chronometer.stop();

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
    chronometer.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at a fragment and the fragment's lifecycle (onAttach, onPause... )

To resolve issue, you need to also understand [ViewPager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) <-> [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java?av=f),
and how ViewPager delegates UI changes on swipe events on the UI.

Focus on the 'Listener' in ViewPager and get your calls to StopChronometer inserted into an implementation of the pagechangeListener.

OnPause is not getting called in the delegated event handlers from a swipedPage...

However, if you understand the collaboration of these 3 classes and maybe look over some github example using those classes or look over one of the ADT sample ViewPager apps, then you should be able to hook them up so that you can insert your StopChronometer code into a correct place within the call-chain that results from a page-swipe.

Comment: Robert,   Thank you very much. Implemented pagechangeListener piece of code on the pager and it looks good now. Appreciate your help.